# Prove an implication in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove for any integer $x$:

if $x^{13} = 1 \mod \ 17$ then $x = 1 \mod 17$

Answer (score 1):

$$x=(x^{13})^5(x^{16})^{-4}$$

Now apply Fermat little theorem

This will hold true for any odd integer $m$

All we need to find is Integers $a,b$ such that $$am+16b=1$$ which is always available using

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Bezout%27s_Lemma

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Take $x^{13}\equiv1\bmod17$ and raise both sides to the fifth power.

Comment: $5\times13=65=4\times16+1\equiv1\bmod16$, so using Fermat's Little Theorem $x^{65}\equiv x\bmod17$

Comment: We are currently studying that theorem I should have tried to exploit it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since $17$ is a prime, all members of the multiplicative group mod $17$ have order dividing $17-1 = 16$.  Since $13$ and $16$ are coprime, the order must be $1$, i.e. $x \equiv 1$.